# How to get C documentation in Netbeans?

Tags: c, netbeans, netbeans-7

I used Netbeans for Java and now I installed the C/C++ plugin. Everything (compiling, hints, my inline documentation) works just fine. But the native function documentation just doesn't work. When I click the *scanf()* functin, I see this in the Documentation window:

```
Function int scanf(const char*, ...)
No documentation found.
```

And that's quite frustrating. I'm on Windows 7 if that helps in any way. How can I get the documentation I can see on - for example - Netbeans on Gentoo on PCs on my Uni? I'm pretty sure Netbeans isn't getting firewalled (I assume it's an online documentation) since updating and downloading plugins works.

Optionally, can I somehow use an offline version of that documentation?

Comment: You can also use a browser, the first hit of googling 'scanf' returns a man page.

Comment: @CharlieBurns That's kind of ignoring the point of the question.

Comment: @millimoose, it was a comment, not an answer. Sometimes the path of least resistance is best. But, sorry if I offended you.

Comment: That was just an example. I need the docs even for the native function hinting, since I can see like 10 similar functions but have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: A possible solution (needs verifying): https://forums.netbeans.org/topic9958.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NOTE: I'm assuming that you have installed cygwin to get C/C++

Netbeans looks up the documentation for functions and such using the 'man' pages through the man command -- if you are familiar with linux systems, it's just opens manual/guides for programs, commands and other useful stuff in order to explain how it's used to users.

**Solution**

So the issue is that you are **missing** the those man pages that you would needed to install from cygwin. I believe you are be missing this

```
man-pages-posix
```

Search for it and install it when you run the setup for cygwin.

After installing it, Apart from the posix manual, I also got 'manuals' for functions like `scanf(..)` and `atoi(..)` and the rest of the C standard library.

That should solve it. I did this and now i have documentation for those functions. Ty for this question.

Comment: I no longer have the issue (or Netbeans for that matter), but this does seem like that would've been the issue. I have accepted the answer; if it's incorrect feel free to edit / comment / post a better one.